# Is there a way to edit the same cell across multiple Google Sheet Files?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, edit, cells

I have about 40 different google sheet files that i need to change the color/date of a small little area every couple of months.

As far as i have found, there IS a way to edit the same cell across a sheets multiple pages. However, I have not found a way to edit the same cell across multiple sheets.

```
var color = Browser.inputBox("Enter the color");
var sheet = spreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Same link as if i was editing it actively from my browser");
sheet.getRange("M18").setBackground(color);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: If you know the file ID or URL, you could use Apps Script code to get a reference to every spreadsheet, and use the `setFontColor()` and/or `setBackground(color)` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I've since learned 300% more javascript than I have in my entire life. However, my script isn't working at the moment. This is what i'm using. `var color = Browser.inputBox("Enter the color")
  var sheet = spreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Same link as if i was editing it actively from my browser")
  sheet.getRange("M18").setBackground(color)` Do you see anything that i may be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array of spreadsheet ID's, then loop through the array.

```
function updateColor() {
  var spreadsheetIDs = ["ssID_One","ssID_Two","ssID_Three","ssID_etc"];
  var i,color="",sheet,thisID="",L=0;
  
  L = spreadsheetIDs.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    thisID=spreadsheetIDs[i];
    color = Browser.inputBox("Enter the color");
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisID).getSheetByName('sheetNameHere');
    sheet.getRange("M18").setBackground(color);
  };
};
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. I will just have to make sure that on each file the sheets are setup the same. Many thanks, you've saved me a lot of future work.